# Difference between TimeDistributed and convLSTM2D layer in Keras?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, lstm, keras

I am working on RNN(CLSTM) and in examples i see somewhere

```
layers.convLSTM2D()
```

and somewhere i see

```
layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D())
```

What is the difference between the two? Are they same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConvLSTM2D` is an implementation of paper [Convolutional LSTM Network: A Machine Learning
Approach for Precipitation Nowcasting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04214v1.pdf) that introduces a special architecture that combines gating of LSTM with 2D convolutions. The architecture **is recurrent**: it keeps is a hidden state between steps.

`TimeDistributed` wraps a layer and when called, it applies on every time slice of the input. Here you would need the input of shape $B \times T \times a \times b \times c$ (where $B$ is batch, $T$ sequence length, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are dimensions of every time slice). `layers.TimeDistributed(Conv2D())` will iterate over the first dimension and independently apply a 2D convolution on tensors of shape $B \times a \times b \times c$. No gating, **no recurrence** going on.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. However, i am still a bit confused in the coding part. As i have 10,000 images/cycle of length(28x28). I am confused about timesteps. Can you answer on the following link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59822799/how-to-deal-with-the-size-of-images-and-filters-if-we-use-covolutional-lstm-co)